# What is the difference between .addRules() and .embedRules() in AceJS?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

From Ace documentation:

```
Like addRules, embedRules adds on to the existing this.$rules object.
```

And from the given examples I see no difference between these two methods.

So,

What is the difference between these two methods? Can you provide examples of using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/text_highlight_rules.js#L53-L104
embedRules calls addRules internally, but takes a different set of parameters.

Basically embedRules allows to take highlight rules constructor of a language add escape rules and add resulting rules to the language

```
this.embedTagRules(
   JavaScriptHighlightRules,
   "js-", 
   [{regex: "</script>", token: "tag"}], // token that should return to initial state
   undefined, // add escape rules to all js states
   false      // escape rules should match before js rules
)
```